# Working with flatmap and tap with Angular 8 and Guard

Tags: angular, jwt, nebular

I am trying to create a guard for my routes based on the payload I received in the JWT token. The problem is that I have the first method (authService.getToken()) returning an Observable of NbJWTAuthToken and then I need to query again using the token like in token.getPayload() to then retrieve the payload.

Here is what I tried without much success:

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: NbAuthService) { }

    canActivate() {

        return this.authService.getToken()
           .pipe(
               flatmap(token => token.getPayload()),
               tap((account:Account) => account.type === AccountType.ADMIN)
           );
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close. Just use Rxjs '**map**' operator instead of '**tap**'.

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: NbAuthService) { }

  canActivate() {
    return this.authService.getToken()
      .pipe(
        flatmap(token => token.getPayload()),
        map((account:Account) => account.type === AccountType.ADMIN)
      );
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

**canActivate()** method can accepts return type of **Observable<boolean>**.
In your Observable you were using tap operator which returns nothing (void). Using the map operator you can return a boolean result (as you already have in the question).